# Saving/loading files: "warning: dynamic accessors failed to find @property implementation for 'uniqueId'"

Tags: swift, macos

I am trying to save/load an object to file, and for this I am just converting the object (*self.game*) to an array containing dictionaries, and then using write(toFile:atomically:). But the saveGame method doesn't do anything: I am allowed to choose a file, to press OK and the save panel gets dismissed, but the file isn't really saved. When I use the loadGame method I see that a strange error appears:

> warning: dynamic accessors failed to find @property implementation for 'uniqueId' for entity ABCDInfo while resolving selector 'uniqueId' on class 'ABCDInfo'.  Did you remember to declare it @dynamic or @synthesized in the @implementation ?

```
@IBAction func saveGame(_ sender: NSButton) {
    let savePanel = NSSavePanel()
    savePanel.allowedFileTypes = ["com.apple.property-list"]
    if savePanel.runModal() == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton {
        let file = savePanel.url!.absoluteString
        self.game.write(toFile: file)
    }
}

@IBAction func loadGame(_ sender: NSButton) {
    let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
    openPanel.allowedFileTypes = ["com.apple.property-list"]
    if openPanel.runModal() == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton {
        let file = openPanel.url!.absoluteString
        self.game = Game(withFile: file)
        self.selectedSlot = nil
        self.enemySlot = nil
        self.restartButton.isEnabled = false
        self.updateTurnLabel()
        self.chessboardView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

The self.game.write(toFile:) method just converts the object to a NSArray and writes it to the file passed as argument.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you save an array with a dictionary, you can simply use `writeToFile` in Objective-C.  But the same is not true for Swift unless the keys are absolutely string objects.  You have to first archive it with `NSKeyedArchiver`.  You can then write it to a file.  If you don't archive it, you can end up with no file with or without a warning.  The following is an example.

```
let title = recordArray[r1].valueForKey("texttitle") as! String
let text = recordArray[r1].valueForKey("texttext") as! String
let urls = recordArray[r1].valueForKey("urls") as! String
var codeArray = [NSDictionary]()
let dict = ["Title":title,"URLs":urls,"Code":text] as NSDictionary // or Dictionary
codeArray.append(dict)
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(codeArray)
data.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
```

When you open a file, use `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to unarchive data.